# Write contents of dataframe to .txt files with one file per row?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a two column data frame with nrows.

```
Col1  Col2
123   abc
456   def
```

I would like to loop through the data frame and for each row create a text file.  The first column is the text file name and the second column is the text file contents.

Result:

- 123.txt with contents abc
- 456.txt with contents def

Comment: I assume you're using pandas?

Comment: Yes I 'm using Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `pandas`. Even if it is a bit ugly it does the job, and will get you on the way.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'food': ['eggs','eggs','ham','ham'],'co1':[20,19,20,21]})

for x in df.iterrows():
    #iterrows returns a tuple per record whihc you can unpack
    # X[0] is the index
    # X[1] is a tuple of the rows values so X[1][0] is the value of the first column etc.
    pd.DataFrame([x[1][1]]).to_csv(str(x[1][0])+".txt", header=False, index=False)
```

This will save the text files in you working directory.

Answer (score 0):

A simple base python solution would be (not using PANDAS) :

```
lines = ["123 abc","456 def"]

def writeToFile(line):
    words=line.split()
    f = open(words[0]+'.txt','wb')
    f.write(words[1])
    f.close()

map(writeToFile,lines)
```